# Cycles settings Light paths

Tags: rendering

Where I can found more information about light path settings. For example, what diffuse bounces do, what is transmission etc?

Comment: How about the official [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/light_paths.html)? Too short? Nice Intro to *path tracing*: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=frLwRLS_ZR0

Comment: Thank you. Yes manual was vry basic. Vry nice intro it shows how complex ant time consuming rendering is when we do not organize rays. I guess If I set more diffuse bounces that mean that renderer calculate more rays where is diffusion (scattered light)?

Comment: Correct, the value determines how often the rays *are allowed* to bounce/reflect in the scene. You can proof that by yourself by setting the value to 1 and compare against any other render.